# Changing remote path of figures to local path with a regular expression

Tags: markdown, substitution, l3regex

I am using markdown to write the bulk of my thesis, and then converting it to LaTeX (with Pandoc) for the final presentation. To include graphics I use dropbox share links as:

`![MyCaption](http://Dropboxlink/Myfigure1.png?dl=1)`

This is handy as most of the times I write from a Chromebook which cannot store many figures.

When I convert it to LaTeX I get:
`\includegraphics{https://www.dropbox.com/bla/bla/Myfigure1.png?dl=1}`

Back in my desktop I need to manually rename the remote paths to my local path, (as \includegraphics cannot not handle remote paths).

Could someone help me with the regular expression to substitute all \includegraphics instances to point to a local path (but keeping the filename from the last slash onwards)?

Something that would do this:

`\includegraphics{https://www.dropbox.com/bla/bla/Myfigure1.png?dl=1}` change to `\includegraphics{./figures/Myfigure1.png}`

Thanks a lot for your help!

Papo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\def\includegraphics#1{\zzz#1\relax}
\def\zzz#1/bla/bla/#2?#3\relax{\oldincludegraphics{figures/#2}}
```

Probably works.

Comment: The `bla/bla`-part of the URL is different for every share, so it will be something like `\def\zzz#1dropbox.com/s/#2/#3?#4\relax`.

Comment: @ralfix yes perhaps, or just trim off up to dropbox.com and have the local figure directory match the dropbox layout or....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you both for your answers. It is working perfectly!

Comment: `\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\def\includegraphics#1{\zzz#1\relax}
\def\zzz#1dropbox.com/s/#2/#3?#4\relax{\oldincludegraphics{../figures_all/#3}}
`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with regular expressions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_papo_path_tl

% save the meaning of \includegraphics    
\cs_set_eq:NN \papo_original_includegraphics:wn \includegraphics

% define a wrapper around the original \includegraphics
% to be able to add a variant    
\cs_new_protected:Npn \papo_include_graphics:nn #1 #2
 {
  \papo_original_includegraphics:wn [#1]{#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \papo_include_graphics:nn { nV }

% the main command
\cs_set_protected:Npn \papo_drop_include_graphics:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_papo_path_tl { #2 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A .*/ } { ./ } \l_papo_path_tl
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { ? .* \Z } { } \l_papo_path_tl
  \papo_include_graphics:nV { #1 } \l_papo_path_tl
 }

% redefine \includegraphics
\RenewDocumentCommand{\includegraphics}{O{}m}
 {
  \papo_drop_include_graphics:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=3cm]{https://www.dropbox.com/bla/bla/duck.jpg?dl=1}

\end{document}
```

With `\A .* /` we search everything up to the last `/` starting from the beginning, which is replaced by `./`; with `? .* \Z` we search everything from the first `?` up to the end of the string.

The rest is syntactic sugar.

I used the `draft` option that shows the file name that's passed to `\includegraphics`, just by way of example.

[image]